# How to install drivers for Samsung printer ml-2955 on Ubuntu 13?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, samsung

I tried to install 2 versions of printer drivers.

1. specifically for Samsung printer ml-2955.
2. the other one generic linux driver.

I do not know how to install neither of them. There is autorun file which opens window with this content>

```
#! /bin/sh
BASE=`dirname "$0"`
exec sh "$BASE/Linux/install.sh"
```

Now I have no idea what to do with that :(

The other version is similar (no autorun but similar window content).

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal by pressing `ctrl + alt + t` and

type :
`sh filename`

Replace filename with the present filename.

It would install the driver .